# Table view scrolling behind title bar creates artifacts as blur update lags

Tags: swift, macos, nstoolbar, nsvisualeffectview

I noticed that projects that I compile on Xcode 9 (beta then, release now) have all a strange behavior. When a view scrolls behind the title bar (either with toolbar or not) the blur/translucency fails to update as quick as the scroll occurs and it results on artifacts appearing.
It looks like this :
[image]

> You can notice how the blue highlight from the selected table view cell left a mark on the title bar blur.

[image]

> Same here but it is just a portion of the bar.

I also made a [video so anyone can see it live.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP0pn.jpg)

I tried to compile the same test project on 2 different machines but the result is the same. One of the machines is running up on a fresh install. Both are macOS 10.13/Xcode 9.0

This test project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Pyroh/VibrancyTest).

Does anyone have an idea on what is happening ? If not I'll file a radar.